# How to handle @jupyterlab/apputils Dialog click events | Jupyterlab Extension

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

According to the documentation https://jupyterlab.github.io/jupyterlab/apputils/classes/dialog.html, Dialog constructor gets buttons array whose elements implements IButton interface. However, IButton does not have any onclick event https://jupyterlab.github.io/jupyterlab/apputils/interfaces/dialog.ibutton.html.

Dialog has handleEvent function, yet it is hard to understand from which button the click is triggered. The only solution I found is to give ids/classes to buttons, make child nodes unclikable(to make comparison easy) and then compare src element of click with all button ids/classes.
The ugly solution:

```
dialog.handleEvent = e => {
  if (e.type === "click") {
    const elm: any = e.srcElement;
    if (elm.classList.contains("jp-Dialog")) {
      if (elm.classList.contains("cancel-btn")) {
        // handle cancel
      } else if(elm.classList.contains("success-btn")) {
        // handle success
      }
    }
  }
};
```

There should be a better way, but I could not find even by checking the documentation.